# How to get "make" for Solaris 10

Tags: makefile, solaris

My current project involves writing Perl code inside a Solaris VMWare appliance (hosted on a Mac).

In order to use the CPAN, I need to install a version of "make" inside the VM.

What is the most frugal apprach (disk space and download capacity are limited) to do this?

---

**EDIT:** turns out I have a Solaris 10, after all.
         Timo Geusch's answer still stands. I'll report if and how I got it to work, after the fact. Thx Timo

---

**EDIT:** 
Here's how I downloaded and installed make:

1. downloaded [make-3.81-sol10-x86-local.gz](ftp://ftp.sunfreeware.com/pub/freeware/intel/10/make-3.81-sol10-x86-local.gz) and [libgcc-3.4.6-sol10-x86-local.gz](ftp://ftp.sunfreeware.com/pub/freeware/intel/10/libgcc-3.4.6-sol10-x86-local.gz) from sunfreeware.com.
2. used secure copy to transfer them from OSX to the Solaris VM.
3. logged into the vm as root, cd to /tmp
4. gunzip both files
5. pkgadd -d both extracted files, answered the prompts ..
6. **DONE**

Thx again Timo.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [sunfreeware](http://www.sunfreeware.com/) site has a prebuilt version of GNU Make 3.81 for Solaris 9 - that is probably your best best.

Comment: I've donwloaded and transfered make-3.81-sol10-sparc-local.gz (and the libgcc-3.4.6 it needs) to my VM. Unpacking resulted in fewer files than expected .. moving them to /usr/local/lib and /user/local doesn't result in a working make .. my lack of unix-oid knowhow shows. sigh

Comment: First, for Solaris 9 you need the Solaris 9 version. Also, if you're on a Mac, you most likely want the x86 version and not the Sparc version. Also, have a look at the Download/Installation link as that should tell you how to properly install them using pkgadd.

Comment: Turns out I have solaris 10 (doc claims 9, might be old, but I never checked, so mea culpa)

Answer (score 5):

Check in /usr/ccs/bin for the make included with Solaris, if you installed at least the "Developer" level install choice/package cluster.

Comment: thxs for the tip .. yes, there's a make present in that location ..

Answer (score 3):

Note that /usr/ccs/bin/make is not gnumake.  The makefiles have mostly the same syntax, but, gnumake has extensions that programs do use.

With some small edits you probably can build gnumake with starting with /usr/ccs/bin/make.